# Unable to use Windows Authentication IIS

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

Here is an extract of my Web.Config for the windows authentication settings.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
<authorization>
  <!-- The following roles are group memberships in Active Directory. -->
  <allow roles="domain\finance,domain\it" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Im using .net 4.0 classic pipemode: classic

Within IIS I have the following Authentication settings applied:

```
Anonymous Autehntication: Disabled
ASP.Net Impersonation: Enabled
Basic Authentication: Disabled
Digest Authetication: Disabled
Forms Authetication: Disabled
Windows Authentication: Enabled
```

When accessing the page from a user account within a role (AD Group) i am presented with a username / password window :(

here is the entire web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="it@domain.com">
                <network host="10.0.0.150" port="25" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <system.web>

        <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />

        <customErrors mode="Off" />


    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="domain\finance,domain\it" />
    </authorization>

    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I changed your tag from asp-classic to asp.net.  The pipeline mode in IIS has **nothing** to do with Classic ASP (the old *.asp files).

Comment: You're allowing roles, but your denying *all* users - `<deny users="*">`.  That's why you're being presented with the username/password window.  Try `<deny users="?">`, which will deny all unauthenticated users.

Comment: thank you @Tim. What would I use to deny all others?

Comment: Actually, I just double-checked (I haven't done authentication rules in Web.Config in a loooong time), and it appears that your code should work.  Are you sure the role names are correct?  Maybe just the role name without the domain prefix?

Comment: Yeah, I have give that a try also. Same issue. Is there anything else i could supply to aid your assistance?

Comment: Where those groups recently created or were you (or the account your using) recently added to either of those?  If so, you might try logging out and logging back in with that account.

Comment: the groups have existed for years. i have also tried logging off / on to check, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution can be:

1. Making sure that you are using Internet explorer based browser, since Windows Authentication gets your login credentials via IE, otherwise request for credentials is a normal behavior.
2. If you are using IE - make sure that the site you are accessing is added to "Local intranet" sites
3. Check the physical folder you are deploying the solution to, because there can be certain ntfs permissions denying access and thus asking for creds.